# Sending file to print not working using System.Drawing.Printing

Tags: c#, asp.net, printing, system.drawing, printqueue

I'm trying to send a file to print without opening it trough Adobe as suggested by several Answers here; instead, I'm using the `PrintQueue` library (from `System.Drawing.Printing`).

What I've accomplished so far:

I have the correct `PrintQueue` referenced as pq:

```
PrintQueue pq; //Assume it's correct. The way to get here it isn't easy and it is not needed for the question.

// Call AddJob
PrintSystemJobInfo myPrintJob = pq.AddJob();

// Write a Byte buffer to the JobStream and close the stream
Stream myStream = myPrintJob.JobStream;
Byte[] myByteBuffer = ObjectIHave.ToArray(); //Ignore the ObjectIhave, it actually is Linq object which is correct as well.
myStream.Write(myByteBuffer, 0, myByteBuffer.Length);
myStream.Close();
```

As I understood from the Microsoft [Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552912(v=vs.110).aspx) it's correctly done but it is not working. Any ideas?

EDIT: Debugging the code I can see that something is being send to the printer but it seems the file is not sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to render your PDF to the printer. Calling the shell `print` verb on the file would be the ideal means to do that. If you insist on doing the low level rendering yourself then I recommend using a library like [Ghostscript.NET](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET) and [choose the `mswinpr2` device as output](http://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.06/Devices.htm#Win).

> The mswinpr2 device uses MS Windows printer drivers, and thus should work with any printer with device-independent bitmap (DIB) raster capabilities. The printer resolution cannot be selected directly using PostScript commands from Ghostscript: use the printer setup in the Control Panel instead.

See [SendToPrinterSample.cs](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/c043411363ec327b044146dfdbeb7c21ea482e4e/Ghostscript.NET.Samples/Samples/SendToPrinterSample.cs) for example:

```
        string printerName = "YourPrinterName";
        string inputFile = @"E:\__test_data\test.pdf";

        using (GhostscriptProcessor processor = new GhostscriptProcessor())
        {
            List<string> switches = new List<string>();
            switches.Add("-empty");
            switches.Add("-dPrinted");
            switches.Add("-dBATCH");
            switches.Add("-dNOPAUSE");
            switches.Add("-dNOSAFER");
            switches.Add("-dNumCopies=1");
            switches.Add("-sDEVICE=mswinpr2");
            switches.Add("-sOutputFile=%printer%" + printerName);
            switches.Add("-f");
            switches.Add(inputFile);

            processor.StartProcessing(switches.ToArray(), null);
        }
```

If the file has to be printed in both sides you just need to add:

```
switches.Add("-dDuplex");
switches.Add("-dTumble=0");
```

Comment: I know that this is not a licensing-expert platform, but are there any implications on how your software must be licensed for using Ghostscript?

Comment: It's kinda working. I installed the licence and added the .dll reference and the file was sent to print :); Now I'm just trying to figure out how to use the print system preferences since it's printing page by page instead of 2-sides copies. I'lll keep you informed.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Licensing is [AGPL](https://github.com/jhabjan/Ghostscript.NET/blob/master/COPYING), not exactly as liberal as MIT, but neither as constraining as LGPL. Something for OP to consider, obviously.

Comment: @MiquelColl the same link has an example as how to set Duplex printing (2-sided): *The following example shows how to print on both faces of the paper (using the long side of the paper as the reference):* `<< /Duplex true /Tumble false >> setpagedevice`

Comment: ir works nice! There are some problems with the margins which the same documentation mentions but I can make a work-around around that. Thank you Remus.

Answer (score 2):

You can not just write PDF bytes to a print job. The printer doesn't know how to handle it. The RAW data you send to the printer must describe the document in a printer language specific to the printer. That's what the printer driver does.

You can not print a PDF by just sending it to the printer. You need some piece of software that renders the PDF and then sends the rendered image to the printer.

As the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms552912(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> Use this method to write **device specific** information, to a spool file, that is not automatically included by the Microsoft Windows spooler.

I enhanced the important part of this information.

Comment: True. The printer won't know how to read a pdf file. I'm trying to render the pdf file now before Sending it to the printer (transforming it to a PNG) or using the lubrary suggested by Remus. I'm on it.